# Binding a redux store to a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have these routes that I want wrapped into a `checkAuth` method to see the session state of the visitor. To keep the code clean I separated the `checkAuth` method to a separate file and imported it into the file with routes declaration:

```
import {checkAuth} from 'helpers/core'

export default ( store ) => {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory} onEnter={checkAuth.bind(store)}>
            <Route path={AUTH_ROUTE} component={AuthLayout}>
                <IndexRoute component={AuthView}/>
            </Route>

            <Route component={CoreLayout}>
                <Route path={DASHBOARD_ROUTE} component={AuthView}/>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

`checkAuth` needs the `store` to read state and also dispatch some actions so I'm unsure how to pass it. I tried with bind as you can see in my code but `console.log(this)` returns undefined inside the method.

Here's the `checkAuth` code:

```
export const checkAuth = ( desiredRoute, redirect ) => {
    console.log(this);// returns undefined
    const state = this.getState();// Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined
    const isAuthenticated = state.auth.loggedIn;
    ....
};
```

Comment: What prevents you from requiring the `store` in your `checkAuth` module?

Comment: `onEnter` should not call the function so I can't put parenthesis in there and simply pass store as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using arrow functions, so you can't `bind` anything to them. That's why your console call returns `undefined`.

You can import the store directly in your `checkAuth` module:

```
import store from 'path/to/store';
export const checkAuth = ( desiredRoute, redirect ) => {
  const state = store.getState();
}
```

And use it simply as `onEnter={checkAuth}`.

Or you can make a factory:

```
export const checkAuth = ( store ) => ( desiredRoute, redirect ) => {
  const state = store.getState();
}
```

And pass it the store: `onEnter={checkAuth(store)}`.

Or just use normal functions.

Comment: Thanks. Learned a few new things from your answer: you can't bind to an arrow function and factories.